# How to connect to Couchbase 2.0+ using lcb_create C API?

Tags: c, authorization, couchbase

I am returning to a C API Couchbase 2.0 project which was working a year ago and now fails to connect to the database, on a computer and source code that I believe has not changed, except for Ubuntu updates.

I now get the following error when I attempt to call lcb_create:

> Failed to create libcouchbase instance: The administrative account can
>   no longer be used for data access

Have lcb_create parameters or behavior changed? What do I now need to provide?

My code is:

```
  // Create the database instance:
  lcb_error_t err;

  struct lcb_create_st create_options;
  struct lcb_create_io_ops_st io_opts;
  io_opts.version = 0;
  io_opts.v.v0.type = LCB_IO_OPS_DEFAULT;
  io_opts.v.v0.cookie = NULL;
  memset(&create_options, 0, sizeof(create_options));
  err = lcb_create_io_ops(&create_options.v.v0.io, &io_opts);
  if (err != LCB_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create libcouchbase IO instance: %s\n",
    lcb_strerror(NULL, err));
    return 1;
  }

  create_options.v.v0.host = Host;
  create_options.v.v0.user = Username;
  create_options.v.v0.passwd = Password;
  create_options.v.v0.bucket = Bucket;

  err = lcb_create(&Instance, &create_options);
  if (err != LCB_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create libcouchbase instance: %s\n",
    lcb_strerror(NULL, err));
    return 1;
  }
```

The Username I am passing is has been the Administrator name, and as I said this used to work. Reading around, it sounds like now we use the bucket name as the user name? Is the bucket field then redundant? And the password is now a bucket password? I don't see a place to set that - maybe I need to update Couchbase Server past 2.0, and the updates have made my API out of sync with the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the bucketname and password to connect to the bucket, not the Administrator name.  This is covered in the release notes for the [Couchbase C client 2.1.1](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-c-2.3/#release-notes-for-couchbase-client-library-c-211-ga-22-august-2013).

The use of Administrator credentials was never documented, was not a good security practice and was rarely used, so Couchbase decided to address the issue.

Comment: Thanks! This did work, BTW. I just had to replace the username with the bucket name, and set password to a blank string.